# 2004 Honda Civic error code P0340

Tags: honda, transmission, civic, p0340

I have a 2004 Honda Civic and have been having some issues with what I thought was the transmission until I read the `P0340` code which is a problem with the camshaft sensor.

My car while accelerating would occasionally would not be able to change gears as well as slowly lose power to move. The engine has also turned off while the car was stopped. Would the camshaft sensor malfunction cause those problems?

Comment: Change the camshaft sensor. What engine do you have?